# hyperledger fabric-ca server configure with openldap

Tags: ldap, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Does anyone successfully configured `Fabric-CA (1.2.0-stable)` server with `openldap` server?

I am seeing this error in the logs:

```
2018/09/03 01:34:01 [DEBUG] Creating new LDAP client for { Enabled:true URL:ldap://****:****@openldap/dc=example,dc=com UserFilter:(uid=%s) GroupFilter:(memberUid=%s) Attribute:{[uid member][{ }] map[groups:[{ }]]} TLS:{false [] { }}  }
2018/09/03 01:34:01 [DEBUG] Initialized LDAP identity registry; err=Invalid expression for attribute '': Unexpected end of expression
2018/09/03 01:34:01 [WARNING] Failed to initialize LDAP client; err=Invalid expression for attribute '': Unexpected end of expression
2018/09/03 01:34:01 [ERROR] Error occurred initializing database: Invalid expression for attribute '': Unexpected end of expression
```

This is the command which I am using to start `openldap`:

```
docker run -h openldap -p 389:389 --name openldap --network=fabric-n --volume /home/xxxx/fabric-ca/data:/etc/hyperledger --env LDAP_ORGANISATION="Hyperledger" --env LDAP_DOMAIN="example.com"  --env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="adminpw" --detach osixia/openldap:1.2.1
```

This is the command that run `fabricca`:

```
docker run -h fabric-ca -p 7054:7054 --name fabric-ca --network=fabric-n --volume /home/xxxx/fabric-ca/data:/etc/hyperledger --env FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME="/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server" --env FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME="/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-client" --env FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME="hfca" --detach hyperledger/fabric-ca:amd64-1.2.0
```

I created a docker overlay network which can connect to openldap container

```
fabric-ca-server-config.yaml

ldap:
  # Enables or disables the LDAP client (default: false)
  # If this is set to true, the "registry" section is ignored.
enabled: true
  # The URL of the LDAP server
url: ldap://cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com:adminpw@openldap/dc=example,dc=com
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is most probably caused because of missing  `converters` properties set below in `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` file.
By default, in `ldap` section there are `converters` which are empty:

```
      converters:
         - name:
           value:
```

And when `ldap` is enabled, it cannot be properly parsed, so error is raised. Please put any values there, so something  like:

```
      converters:
         - name: hf.Revoker
           value: attr("uid") =~ "revoker*"
```